# what is " invalid index 90 size is 90 " in android

Tags: android, button

I am getting an error " invalid index  90 size is 90 " how to fix this?

```
package com.example.micro;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;    
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
import android.widget.Button;    
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        task_final();

    }
    //  Button btn;
        //btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //public void onClick(View v) {
                // write on SD card file data in the text box
        public void task_final()
        {
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            String aDataRow = "";
            StringTokenizer st = null;
            String start=null;
            String mid=null;
            String end=null;
            String sm_time,sn_time,mm_time,mn_time,em_time,en_time;
            try {
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(dir, "/Notes/task_name5.csv");
                FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("/sdcard/Notes/delay.csv");  
                BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(outFile);


                //ArrayList<String> e1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                    st = new StringTokenizer(aDataRow,",");
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    al.add(st.nextToken());
                      }//while
                }//while
                int i=0,j;

                do
                {
                    start=al.get(i);
                    sm_time=al.get(i+1);
                    sn_time=al.get(i+2);
                    mid=al.get(i+3);
                    mm_time=al.get(i+4);
                    mn_time=al.get(i+5);
                    j=i+3;

                    while((start.equals(mid)))
                    {
                           j+=3;
                           mid=al.get(j);

                    }
                    end=al.get(j-3);
                    em_time=al.get(j-2);
                    en_time=al.get(j-1);
                  /*  if(i!=(j-3)){
                    System.out.print(start);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(sm_time);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(sn_time);
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    System.out.print(end);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(em_time);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(en_time);
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    }*/
                       if(i!=(j-3))
                       {
                           s1.add(start);
                           s1.add(sm_time);
                           s1.add(sn_time);
                           s1.add(end);
                           s1.add(em_time);
                           s1.add(en_time);
                       }
                    i=j;
                }while(i<al.size());

                for (int k = 0; k < s1.size(); k+=3)  
                {
                outStream.write(s1.get(k));
                outStream.write(",");    
                outStream.write(s1.get(k+1));
                outStream.write(",");
                outStream.write(s1.get(k+2));
                outStream.write("\n");

                }
                outStream.close(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: this means the size is 90 and you are acessing the datat at the 90th poistion..if the size is 90 ...postion would be 89th..as it starts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the for loop

```
for (int k = 0; k < s1.size(); k+=3)
```

into

```
for (int k = 0; k < s1.size()-1; k+=3)
```

that too you need to concentrate on this lines

```
          do
            {
                start=al.get(i);
                sm_time=al.get(i+1);
                sn_time=al.get(i+2);
                mid=al.get(i+3);
                mm_time=al.get(i+4);
                mn_time=al.get(i+5);
                j=i+3;

                while((start.equals(mid)))
                {
                       j+=3;
                       mid=al.get(j);

                }
                end=al.get(j-3);
                em_time=al.get(j-2);
                en_time=al.get(j-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing in Java starts at 0 and an array list with 90 elements has indices from 0 to 89. Attempting to index element 90 causes this error.

You didn't specify where exactly you get it, but I assume it's this loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < s1.size(); k+=3)
```

where you access elements `k`, `k+1` and `k+2` but the for loop conditional only checks up to `k`. Change the condition to

```
for (int k = 0; k + 2 < s1.size(); k+=3)
```

to make sure all indices are valid on each iteration.

The other loop has also unchecked array element access. That's certainly a bug, too, though bugs like these may not result in exceptions with all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Change this line

```
for (int k = 0; k < s1.size(); k+=3)
```

with

```
for (int k = 0; k < s1.size()-3; k+=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to k-loop mentioned by others, i-loop might be off too:

```
do {
    start=al.get(i);
    sm_time=al.get(i+1);
    sn_time=al.get(i+2);
    mid=al.get(i+3);
    mm_time=al.get(i+4);
    mn_time=al.get(i+5);

    ...

} while (i < al.size());
```